# The bundle UITests couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle

Tags: ios, swift, travis-ci, uitest

I can't run my test case due to this following errors :

- The bundle “UITests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.
- Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire.
- Reason: image not found

Try searching and solving since two days but couldn't get through this issue can someone please help.

Comment: This is happening to me when i imported a framework which is added via SPM in my UI tests code. Already tried adding the package to the UITest target under  build phases > Link Binary with Libraries but didn't work

Answer (score 32):

I was able to reproduce this issue with the project generated by Xcode 10.1. I used Swift 4.2 and CocoaPods 1.10.0 as a dependency manager. I had the following Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp
  pod 'Alamofire', '4.8.1'

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'MyAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Then I removed `use_frameworks!`, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49469205/2229783) for more details:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'MyApp' do

  # Pods for MyApp
  pod 'Alamofire', '4.8.1'    

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'MyAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I also received some warnings like this:

```
[!] The `MyAppUITests [Debug]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyApp-MyAppUITests/Pods-MyApp-MyAppUITests.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

That's why I removed this line from the MyAppUITests build settings:

[image: MyAppUITests build settings]

After that run `pod deintegrate && pod install` and then the problem disappeared.
Probably for projects with more dependencies (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54365549/the-bundle-uitests-couldn-t-be-loadedbecause-it-is-damaged-or-missing-necessary)) you need to use another solution.

Comment: if there were multiple pods, what would be the syntax?

Comment: @RomanPodymov i have same above issue using CocoaPods 1.5.3
This is my pod file,
`# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0' 
target 'MyApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp
 pod 'SwiftMessages'
    pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
    pod 'AlamofireImage'
   .
    pod 'Alamofire'
  target 'MyAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end`

Comment: Hello @JibranSiddiQui. Try to remove `inherit! :search_paths` from `target 'MyAppUITests'`. Or do you need to keep it?

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, @RomanPodymov i tried without  `inherit! :search_paths` but not working, and i also have other CocoaPods lib to beside these mentions. i haven't any idea of uitest before.

Comment: Hello @JibranSiddiQui. I tried to install all these pods and I've got no error. What version of Xcode are you using? Do you have Objective-C or Swift project?

Comment: @RomanPodymov I am using swift and here are my pods `pod 'SwiftMessages'
    pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper'
    pod 'Tabman'
    pod 'PagingMenuController'
    pod 'Kingfisher'
    pod 'Optik'
    pod 'KRPullLoader'
    pod 'AlamofireImage'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'TCPickerView'
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'GooglePlaces'
    pod 'Whisper'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'SwiftGridView'`
now please try

Comment: Hello @JibranSiddiQui. What version of Xcode are using? I was able to reproduce this issue in Xcode 9.4, but since I use Xcode 10.1 everything works fine. Try to update your Xcode instance.

Comment: @JibranSiddiQui I updated my answer. Please check it.

Comment: @bshirley Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54379966/2229783 , it resolves the issue that you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you.  Are there any unintended consequences that can come from this? I got some Swift warnings: "An iOS Deployment Target earlier than 8.0 is not supported by this version of Xcode.  This will update the value for Target 'nanopd' to '8.0' and also the iOS simulator deployment target iPhones_deployment_target is set to 4.3 but the range of of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99?

Comment: @ScottyBlades I think this is a known [issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8069).

Answer (score 23):

It's because your pods only apply to your Framework target and no the tests one. Add the tests target to your podfile.

Example :

```
target 'MyFramework' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
end

target 'MyFrameworkTests' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
end
```

Comment: In addition to using this solution, I also found that at least one source file that's visible to your tests target needs to have `import <Pod>` (in this case, `import Alamofire`) in order to fix the error.

Answer (score 22):

In your tests target change `inherit! :search_paths` to `inherit! :complete`.
See the [documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#inherit_bang) for what this does.

Answer (score 15):

Check that the deployment target in your UITest target Build Settings is set to the same as the host application you are trying to test. In my case, I added the UITesting target later on, and it created it with a default of deployment target iOS 12. If you then try to run the UITest on iOS lower than 12, it gave me the error mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 15):

In my case, I needed to separate the UI tests target with `use_frameworks!`.

Moving the UI tests target from nested structure to its own will not help, if you specified `use_frameworks!` globally somewhere in the top of the **Podfile**.

The **Podfile** with error (original):

```rb
platform :ios, '10.0'

inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProject' do
  pod 'R.swift', '~> 5.0'
  pod 'Moya/RxSwift', '~> 12.0'
  # and other pods

  target 'MyProjectTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

    pod 'iOSSnapshotTestCase', '~> 6.0'
  end

  target 'MyProjectUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end
```

The **Podfile** with error (first try to fix):

```rb
platform :ios, '10.0'

inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

def shared_pods
  pod 'R.swift', '~> 5.0'
end

target 'MyProject' do
  shared_pods

  pod 'Moya/RxSwift', '~> 12.0'
  # and other pods

  target 'MyProjectTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

    pod 'iOSSnapshotTestCase', '~> 6.0'
  end
end

target 'MyProjectUITests' do
  shared_pods
end
```

The final working **Podfile**:

```rb
platform :ios, '10.0'

inhibit_all_warnings!

def shared_pods
  pod 'R.swift', '~> 5.0'
end

target 'MyProject' do
  use_frameworks!

  shared_pods

  pod 'Moya/RxSwift', '~> 12.0'
  # and other pods

  target 'MyProjectTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

    pod 'iOSSnapshotTestCase', '~> 6.0'
  end
end

target 'MyProjectUITests' do
  shared_pods
end
```

Comment: Only the last solution works for me as well. I didn't have to move the use_frameworks! inside the target, though, I left it on the top and it works fine. All the other changes were needed.

Answer (score 9):

I had to add the location of my frameworks to Runpath search Path under targets>mytestTarget>Build Settings>Runpath Search Path

Answer (score 7):

This error happened to me when I added a framework to the project (that's a framework itself, too), and tried to run the tests. I made it optional instead of required, and the tests succeeded. 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Xcode testing problem**

```
The bundle UITests couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle
```

I have run on this problem when tried to run `UI Testing Bundle` for testing a `Framework`

The solution is simple:

```
Build Phases -> + -> New Copy Files Phase -> <select a framework> -> Destination Frameworks
```

[image]

As a result `<UI_Testing_Bundle_name>-Runner.app` is generated

Comment: This worked for me.  My UI Test Bundle was not loading and it didn't recognized a xcframework.  Doing this worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Switching to legacy build system fixed thi issue with Xcode 10.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone encountering this issue using Carthage, I solved it by adding the `/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks` run script phase to the UITest target (rather than just my main app target), and added the framework as an input file.

Answer (score 1):

[image: 1]

[image: 2[![3]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjPhr.png)

1. Go To Build Phases
2. Open Copy Pods Resources and copy the path
3. Paste the path that you have copied from Copy Pods Resources and change tag name resources with frameworks
4. Clean and Build
5. Run your UITestsFile

Comment: question doesn't mention that they use Cocoapods

Comment: what happend when you are using carthage, wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

What solved my problem was following the following steps:
1) delete the UITests target from the pod file. 
Initially, I had the following in the pod file:

```
target 'XUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths   
end
```

2) Deintegrate the pods (with pod deintegrate)

3) Install the pods (with pod install)

4) Clean your project and run the project or your UITest

Comment: But what if you need UI tests in your project?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 11.2 using Apollo framework within another framework. Instead of changing to optional/required, I fixed it by setting to embed.

With this specific error:

> The bundle “XXX” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing
>   necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle. Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/Apollo.framework/Apollo

I had to embed the framework

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, just removing `inherit! :search_paths` without changing the structure of the file or duplicating any pod fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the answer but without an explanation so decided to post mine.

The issue is that UI tests performed in a separate application that controls the main one and so it can't use the main application's frameworks and so if you just inherit paths to frameworks using Cocoapods UI tests app will crash at the startup.

To fix the issue you need to actually copy frameworks to UI tests app or update your Podfile:

```
use_frameworks!
target 'App' do
  pod 'Alamofire'

  target 'App_UnitTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

    pod 'Quick'
    pod 'Nimble'
  end
end

target 'App_UITests' do
  pod 'Alamofire'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error was when build the UITests.
The solution:
The Targer was with a wrong iOS version, I replace with the same version that the tested Target and everything works!!

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem was caused by me referencing a property from an extension on a UIKit class from a framework which wasn't imported in the file where it was referenced. Fixed by not using that property. I'm not sure why it compiled in the first place - that should have been a compile-time error, not a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case simply choosing "My Mac" instead of "My Mac (Mac Catalyst)" allowed me to run the tests.

Answer (score -1):

Try copy every pod for your app target to the UI testing target.
2019 it works.

Answer (score -5):

If you are in fact using Cocoapods, you probably just need to run "pod install" and the build settings will be updated automatically.