# UITest bundle could not be loaded

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

When i run the UITest in my phone it installs and runs as a separate app while giving the following error.

> 2017-07-27 10:44:33.892639+0700 XCTRunner[11886:3502890] Running
>   tests... 2017-07-27 10:44:34.137927+0700 XCTRunner[11886:3502890] The
>   bundle “...UITests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or
>   missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle. 2017-07-27
>   10:44:34.137999+0700 XCTRunner[11886:3502890]
>   (dlopen_preflight(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/75C9B589-CCD4-480D-9E23-BA86878E8B37/...UITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/...UITests.xctest/...UITests):
>   Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac   Referenced
>   from:
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/75C9B589-CCD4-480D-9E23-BA86878E8B37/...UITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/...UITests.xctest/...UITests
>   Reason: image not found)

I am trying to find a solution for this problem more than a day.

I wanted to add UITests to my existing app and added UITest target to my app. I am using both carthage and cocoa-pod. I updated pod file and updated pod then i added frameworks to the UITest target which are installed by carthage.

This is my pod file

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'ExampleApp' do
    pod 'Charts'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 3'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'Google/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end

target 'ExampleAppTests' do
    pod 'Charts'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 3'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
end

target 'ExampleAppUITests' do
    pod 'Charts'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 3'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
end
```

This is my cartfile

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 4.0
github "SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON" "3.0.0"
github "Friend-LGA/LGSideMenuController" ~> 1.0.0
github "TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel" ~> 1.13.4
github "MagicalPanda/MagicalRecord"
```

I could find a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480503/the-bundle-uitests-couldn-t-be-loaded-because-it-is-damaged-or-missing-necessary) from stack overflow but unfortunately it was not helpful. can you please help me to add the UITest target to my project without a issue.

Comment: Running into the same issue.  Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 13):

**Podfile**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

def base_pods
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.24.0'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.24.0'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '4.15.0'
    pod 'FacebookCore', '0.2.0'
    pod 'FacebookLogin', '0.2.0'
    pod 'FacebookShare', '0.2.0'
end
target 'App' do
  base_pods
    target 'AppTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        # Pods for testing
    end

    target 'AppUITests' do
        inherit! :complete
        # Pods for UI testing
    end
end
```

the line `inherit! :complete` is key here

and in **settings for the UITest target**

[image]

**NEXT**:

- clear derived data
- `pod deintegrate && pod install`